# Is my failed re.search an encoding issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

I am trying to strip characters that follow a pattern out of a .txt file but my regex search is returning none.The characters in question look different in the text file than when printed out in the command prompt. I am new to this and only have general knowledge about encoding and decoding.

I believe txt file is encoded using ANSI (Windows-1252 ) and I am using python 3. I have tried searching using several regex patterns. Each regex worked when tested in RegExr, so I don't think that is the problem.

The txt file is a bulk_extractor output file and it looks like this:

```
# BANNER FILE NOT PROVIDED (-b option)
# BULK_EXTRACTOR-Version: 1.5.5 ($Rev: 10844 $)
# Feature-Recorder: email
# Filename: W:\Migration\2010013\Working
# Feature-File-Version: 1.1
W:\Migration
2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article
W:\Migration\2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article▯-39612 j26@yahoo.com   397-1911 or</I> j26@yahoo.com</P> <P>\x0A<TABLE 
W:\Migration
2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article
W:\Migration\2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article▯-45963 jaime.brown@gmail.com   <a href="mailto:jaime.brown@gmail.com?subject=Ask The
```

To clear a few things up first: I know the folder names are not the best but I am an archivist so we have to work with directories and files however they come into us. Also the email listed is an example and not anyone's actual email.

With that out of the way, I am trying to strip the 'Article▯-#####' off the end of the file paths.

When printed in the command prompt the ▯ changes to ô??o so that it now reads 'ô??o-#####'. Hence the 'ô??o' in the regex. 
My code looks like this:

```
with open("email.txt", 'r', encoding = 'cp1252') as file:
    all_lines = file.readlines()
    no_header = all_lines[5:]
print (no_header) #for testing

pattern = re.compile('/(ô[?]{2}o[-][0-9]*)')
for i in range(len(no_header)):
    test = re.search(pattern, no_header[i])
    print (test)
```

Since the regex worked in RegExr, I expected a string matching the pattern to be returned for each line. Instead the search returns none for each line. I have also tried searching for the rectangle character using its Unicode id U+25AF. That didn't work either.

It seems that something is getting lost in translation.  I am used to working with Python 2.7 so I am guessing I am missing something here where encoding/decoding is concerned.

Your help is appreciated! We are doing this to automate our metadata writing process and to protect individuals private email addresses.

Comment: If you have a Unicode character which doesn't exist in cp1252 in there, the encoding almost has to be UTF-8. (ANSI is a complete misnomer in this context, though it seems hard to get rid of.) Are you saying `re.sub(r'Article\u25af-\d+', '')` does not work for you?

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding of this character is `\xE2\x96\xAF` - can you check with a hex editor or similar if these are the actual bytes in the file? See also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Answer (score 0):

Warning, you have a `/`, which is a regex delimiter in Ruby but not in Python.

Also, you could simply use `\S+` to match any [non-whitespace character](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters):

> \S
>       Matches any non-whitespace character; this is equivalent to the class [^ \t\n\r\f\v].

Here's an example:

```
email = """# BANNER FILE NOT PROVIDED (-b option)
# BULK_EXTRACTOR-Version: 1.5.5 ($Rev: 10844 $)
# Feature-Recorder: email
# Filename: W:\Migration\2010013\Working
# Feature-File-Version: 1.1
W:\Migration
2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article
W:\Migration\2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article▯-39612 j26@yahoo.com   397-1911 or</I> j26@yahoo.com</P> <P>\x0A<TABLE 
W:\Migration
2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article
W:\Migration\2010013\Working/Succession planning/Succession Plan Article▯-45963 jaime.brown@gmail.com   <a href="mailto:jaime.brown@gmail.com?subject=Ask The"""

import re
print(re.findall('Article\S+', email))
# ['Article▯-39612', 'Article▯-45963']
print(re.findall('Article\S\-\d+', email))
# ['Article▯-39612', 'Article▯-45963']
```